# How to print page no to PDF using Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF file where I have to print page no on each page of PDF using the Apache PDFBox library in Java.
And Pdf has a table with dynamic content I don't know how many pages my content will be required to print on PDF because it contains a table with dynamic data.

For e.g:-
While creating the PDF a file may have 4 or 5 pages in that case I have to print page no on each page at the footer of the PDF. like below

Let's assume content will be printed on 4 pages in PDF

On page no 1 **Page 1 of 4**

On page no 2 **Page 2 of 4**

On page no 3 **Page 3 of 4**

On page no 4 **Page 4 of 4**

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDMMType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.structure.Row;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.structure.Table;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.structure.cell.TextCell;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

//pdf with table and page no
public class SimplePDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
            final PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

            // create table with header and set default settings like each col width, border, font (family, size), padding etc.
            Table.TableBuilder table = Table.builder()
                    .addColumnsOfWidth(150F, 150F, 150F)
                    .borderWidth(1F)
                    .borderColor(Color.lightGray)
                    .padding(8F)
                    .font(PDType1Font.HELVETICA)
                    .fontSize(10)
                    .addRow(
                            // header column names
                            Row.builder()
                                    .font(PDMMType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD)
                                    .add(TextCell.builder().text("Name").build())
                                    .add(TextCell.builder().text("Age").build())
                                    .add(TextCell.builder().text("Country").build())
                                    .build()
                    );

            //add multiple rows to table
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                table.addRow(
                        Row.builder()
                                .add(TextCell.builder().text("John").build())
                                .add(TextCell.builder().text("20").build())
                                .add(TextCell.builder().text("Any").build())
                                .build()
                );
            }

            //use RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer builder class to repeat header row in all page of pdf
            RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer repeatedHeaderTableDrawer = RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer.builder()
                    .startX(20f)
                    .startY(page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY())
                    .numberOfRowsToRepeat(1) //specify the no of row wants to repeat on each page of pdf
                    .table(table.build())
                    .build();

            //draw the table on pdf document
            repeatedHeaderTableDrawer.draw(() -> document, () -> new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4), 30);

            //Print the page no on each page of pdf because know we know how many no of pages do this pdf has
            //because it print the table on each page based on the data now we can print the page no on each page of pdf
            //for e.g 'Page 1 of 4'    if we have 4 no of page in pdf then this will be the output on the first page of pdf

            int totalNoOfPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
            AtomicInteger pageCounter = new AtomicInteger(1);

            //iterate each page and print page no on each page at the footer of the pdf
            document.getPages().forEach(pdfPage -> {
                float bottomXAxis = pdfPage.getMediaBox().getLowerLeftX();
                float bottomYAxis = pdfPage.getMediaBox().getLowerLeftY();
                String currentPageNo = MessageFormat.format("Page {0} of {1}", pageCounter.getAndIncrement(), totalNoOfPages);
                try {
                    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, pdfPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    contentStream.setFont(PDMMType1Font.HELVETICA, 10);
                    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(bottomXAxis + 15, bottomYAxis + 5);
                    contentStream.showText(currentPageNo);
                    contentStream.endText();
                    contentStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            //save the pdf file
            document.save("example.pdf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("PDF created");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will generate a pdf file that contains the table with repeatable header row on each page of pdf and page no on each page. Results might be slightly different for you but it works for me.
2 libraries are used one is **[Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html)** and **[EasyTable](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable)** to create tables using ApachePDFBox

dependency for libraries are:-

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.22</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
   <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```